# Android - custom GridView Adapter - item at position 0 not updating

Tags: android, gridview, android-arrayadapter

I'm experiencing a weird issue with a custom GridView adapter that I've been unable to solve.

**The GridView Layout**
Each element of my grid has 4 components:

- A Checkbox
- A TextView
- A Spinner

**The GridView Adapter**
Inside my adapter I've added three arrays:

- `CheckBox checkboxesInView[]` stores the checkbox displayed for each element of the grid.
- `boolean checkboxesState[]` stores the states of the checkboxes of each element, it is used to set the state of the checkbox in an element view when it is redrawn.
- `int productsSelected[]` stores the selected item from the dropdown list of each spinner.

Inside the `getView()` method for each element of the grid I set an `onClickListener` to the checkbox and a `onItemSelectedListener` to the spinner.
Inside the `onClickListener` method, whenever a checkbox is clicked the listener changes the state for that checkbox and stores the state in the `checkboxesState` array, *this works fine for all the elements of the grid from position 0 to position n*.
Inside the `onItemSelected` method, whenever a spinner is clicked and an item from its list is selected, the listener stores the position of the item selected and changes the state of the corresponding checkbox, **this works fine for all the elements of the grid EXCEPT for the one at position 0**.

**My Issue**
The checkbox of the element at position 0 is not updated with the latest state set by the spinner's listener. However, if element 0 is hidded and then reappears inside the grid (thanks to an up-down scroll), the checkbox is refreshed and is shown with the right state.

**Code**
The following is the full code for my Adapter:

```
import com.company.app.R;
import com.company.app.classes.CustomTypefaceSpan;
import com.company.app.classes.Product;
import com.company.app.utils.DatabaseWastes;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.util.ArrayList;



public class AdapterProductsGrid extends ArrayAdapter<Product> implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    static class ViewHolder {
        CheckBox selected;
        TextView type;
        ImageView icon;
        Spinner productOptions;
        LinearLayout layoutSpinner;
        int position;
    }

    // declaring ArrayList of Orders
    private Typeface dinotTf, dinotTfBold;
    private Context context;
    private CompoundButton.OnClickListener checkedOnClickListener;
    private ArrayList<ArrayAdapter<Product>> spinnerAdapters;

    private CheckBox checkboxesInView[];
    private boolean checkboxesState[];
    private int productsSelected[];

    private Product productEmpty;

    ArrayList<Product> listProducts;


    public AdapterProductsGrid(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Product> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.context = context;
        this.listProducts = objects;

        dinotTf = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), context.getString(R.string.font_dinot));
        dinotTfBold = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), context.getString(R.string.font_dinot_Bold));

        int size = listProducts.size();
        checkboxesState = new boolean[size];
        productsSelected = new int[size];
        checkboxesInView = new CheckBox[size];

        productEmpty = new Product();
        productEmpty.setProductId(0);
        productEmpty.setName(" - >seleziona<"); // name needs " - " character to be printed correctly

        checkedOnClickListener = new CompoundButton.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View buttonView) {
                checkboxListener(buttonView);
            }
        };

        //init adapters for spinners
        spinnerAdapters = new ArrayList<>();
        DatabaseWastes db = DatabaseWastes.getInstance(context);
        for (Product p : listProducts) {
            // get all products
            ArrayList<Product> productsNames = db.getProducts(p.getCategory(), p.getType());
            if (productsNames.get(0).getName().contains("-")) {
                productsNames.add(0, productEmpty);
            }

            ArrayAdapter<Product> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, productsNames);
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spinnerAdapters.add(adapter);
        }

    }


    @Override
    public
    @NonNull
    View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        GridView gridView = (GridView) parent;
        int firstVisiblePosition = gridView.getFirstVisiblePosition();

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_product_element, parent, false);

            //Log.e("ADAPTER", "NEW view for POSITION  " + position);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.selected = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox_product_selected);
            viewHolder.icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image_product);
            viewHolder.type = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_product_type);
            viewHolder.layoutSpinner = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.layout_spinner_product_options);
            viewHolder.productOptions = (Spinner) convertView.findViewById(R.id.spinner_product_options);

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

        } else {
            Log.e("ADAPTER", "RECYCLING view for POSITION " + position);
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        }


        Product product = listProducts.get(position);
        if (product != null) {

            checkboxesInView[position] = viewHolder.selected;
            viewHolder.selected.setChecked(checkboxesState[position]);
            viewHolder.selected.setTag(position);
            viewHolder.selected.setOnClickListener(checkedOnClickListener);

            viewHolder.type.setTypeface(dinotTfBold, Typeface.BOLD);
            viewHolder.type.setText(product.getType());
            //TODO: get rid of this
            //viewHolder.type.setText(Integer.toString(position));

            if (product.getCategory().equalsIgnoreCase("ufficio")) {
                // for products of category "Ufficio"
                viewHolder.type.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorButtonBlue));

                viewHolder.layoutSpinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                // for products of other categories
                viewHolder.type.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorButtonGreen));
                viewHolder.layoutSpinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                viewHolder.productOptions.setTag(position);

                if (listProducts.get(position).getName().contains("-")) {
                    // for products with several quantity options (1/5kg, 6/10kg, ...)
                    viewHolder.layoutSpinner.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorGridCellGray));

                    viewHolder.productOptions.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    viewHolder.productOptions.setAdapter(spinnerAdapters.get(position));
                    viewHolder.productOptions.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
                    viewHolder.productOptions.setSelection(productsSelected[position]);
                } else {
                    viewHolder.layoutSpinner.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorGrid));
                    viewHolder.productOptions.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        } else {
            //Log.d("ADAPTER", "product  null");
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    private void checkboxListener(View buttonView) {
        CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox) buttonView;
        checkboxesState[(Integer) checkbox.getTag()] = checkbox.isChecked();
        Log.d("ADAPTER GRID CHECKBOX", "checkbox " + (Integer) checkbox.getTag() + " is checked " + checkbox.isChecked());
    }

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
        // store index of product selected
        int index = (Integer) parent.getTag();
        productsSelected[index] = pos; // store the selected product
        checkboxesState[index] = (pos != 0); // set state of checkbox
        checkboxesInView[index].setChecked(checkboxesState[index]); // show state to user

        Log.d("ADAPTER GRID SELECTION", "parentId " + index + ", position " + pos + ", checkbox id " + (Integer) checkboxesInView[index].getTag() + " is " + checkboxesInView[index].isChecked());
    }

    /**
     * @param parent
     */
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        // another interface callback
        Log.d("ADAPTER GRID", "onNothingSelected called");
    }

    public boolean[] getCheckboxesState() { return checkboxesState;}

    public int[] getProductsSelected(){return productsSelected;}

    public ArrayList<ArrayAdapter<Product>> getSpinnerAdapters() {return spinnerAdapters;}
}
```

Please help.
Thanks in advance.